# Does increasing epochs really cause overfitting?

Tags: neural-networks, overfitting

I have a simple 2 hidden layer feed forward neural network.
As I increase the number of epochs, I am getting a much better F1 score for the test dataset.

Overfitting means that model is performing too well on training data, but my model performs well for the unseen test data (20% of dataset).

Is the only cost of more epochs more computation time in my case?

Comment: What happens if you train for 10 times as many epochs? 100 times?

Comment: There is a significant difference when I train for 10 epochs and 50 epochs. I haven't ran for 10 times(100 epochs) because it takes extremely long.